# HttpWebRequest and HttpWebResponse shows old data

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, httpwebrequest, streamreader, httpwebresponse

After updating the data, when the webservice is called, it still fetches old data. New data is loaded only when I logout of the app and then login again.

```
protected async override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
            base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
            parameterValue = this.NavigationContext.QueryString["parameter"];

            Uri UserDetailUrl = new Uri(Constants.WebService.ws_single_user + "?user_id=" + parameterValue);
            HttpWebRequest UserDetailRequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(UserDetailUrl);
            HttpWebResponse UserDetailResponse = (HttpWebResponse)await UserDetailRequest.GetResponseAsync();
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(UserDetailResponse.GetResponseStream());
            string UserDetailString = reader.ReadToEnd();
            reader.Close();
            XDocument XUserDetailDoc = XDocument.Load(new StringReader(UserDetailString));
            if (((XElement)XUserDetailDoc.Element("main")).Element("result").Value == "success")
            {
                txtEmail.Text = ((XElement)XUserDetailDoc.Element("main")).Element("user").Element("email").Value;
                txtFirstName.Text = ((XElement)XUserDetailDoc.Element("main")).Element("user").Element("fname").Value;
                txtLastName.Text = ((XElement)XUserDetailDoc.Element("main")).Element("user").Element("lname").Value;
                txtMobile.Text = ((XElement)XUserDetailDoc.Element("main")).Element("user").Element("mobile").Value;
            }
    }
```

Windows 8 Phone App - using C# and XAML

The GetResponseAsync is as follows:

```
  public static Task<HttpWebResponse> GetResponseAsync(this HttpWebRequest request)
    {
        var taskComplete = new TaskCompletionSource<HttpWebResponse>();
        request.BeginGetResponse(asyncResponse =>
        {
            try
            {
                HttpWebRequest responseRequest = (HttpWebRequest)asyncResponse.AsyncState;
                HttpWebResponse someResponse = (HttpWebResponse)responseRequest.EndGetResponse(asyncResponse);
                taskComplete.TrySetResult(someResponse);
            }
            catch (WebException webExc)
            {
                HttpWebResponse failedResponse = (HttpWebResponse)webExc.Response;
                taskComplete.TrySetResult(failedResponse);
            }
        }, request);
        return taskComplete.Task;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am facing same problem, and i solved by add response header in my server side like this..

```
response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
```

may be this will help you too.

Comment: Yes it certainly helped.. this was probably the best answer.. since I had full control of the server side, I simple added the header("Cache-Control", "no-cache") there.
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 4):

It seems like `HttpWebRequest` is returning cached result. You got a few ways to avoid that:

1. Add a random string to the URL, so a different URL is accessed every time (so `www.example.com/page` becomes `www.example.com/page?random=dsa$fds21`).
2. Disable the response cache, see new code to be added to `OnNavigatedTo`:

-

```
HttpWebRequest UserDetailRequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(UserDetailUrl); 
// Define a cache policy for this request only. 
HttpRequestCachePolicy noCachePolicy = new HttpRequestCachePolicy(HttpRequestCacheLevel.NoCacheNoStore);
request.CachePolicy = noCachePolicy;
```

Comment: You are right, it was returning cached result.. 
The first solution did work for me perfectly.. but I would rather prefer going for the 2nd one. Disabling cache has to be the perfect solution, however, I tried following the link to MSDN, but the solution didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

If your using your own API try turning caching off from that side.